# pip cannot find build dependencies

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install some python libraries using

```
pip install -r requirements
```

The file looks like:

```
spacy>=2.1.0,<2.2.0
matplotlib
pandas
networkx
flask
inflect
```

It was initially giving errors for C++ build tools, but after installing those using the visual studio installer I get the following error.

```
Collecting spacy<2.2.0,>=2.1.0
  Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
```

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\haris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe'
'C:\Users\haris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-iges9uxt\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 
'C:\Users\haris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-49g1awc5\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
cwd: None
```

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
Running setup.py clean for blis
Successfully built preshed
Failed to build blis
```

Do I need to reinstall a newer version of python?

Comment: Do you have a hard requirement for spacy to be between 2.1 and 2.2?

Comment: Not really, this was for a previous project so I continued to use it because there a few changes in the newer spacy versions

Comment: ok, if you can upgrade to python3.9 or 3.10 (i did not test with 3.8 but should work with that too) and just install spacy using `pip install spacy` everything works just fine. i suspect some dependencies for the old version are no longer maintained.